# Improving the code using more advanced Python libraries

Tags: python, dictionary

Which advanced Python libraries should I use to make the following code more succinct and neater?
[image]

```
# The dictionary will be something like:
# {'Jason Seifer': ['Ruby Foundations', 'Ruby on Rails Forms', 'Technology Foundations'],
#  'Kenneth Love': ['Python Basics', 'Python Collections']}
#
# Often, it's a good idea to hold onto a max_count variable.
# Update it when you find a teacher with more classes than
# the current count. Better hold onto the teacher name somewhere
# too!
#
# Your code goes below here.
def most_classes(dict):
    for item in dict:
        count = 0
        max = 0
        teacher = None
        for course in dict[item]:
            count += 1
        if count > max:
            max = count
            teacher = item
    return teacher
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in [`max`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) can be used with a key function that will be applied to each element in the iterable in order to determine the max element. Just return the key of the max `dict` item with regard to its value's length:

```
def most_classes(d):
    return max(d.items(), key=lambda i: len(i[1]))[0]
    # items(): list of (key, value) pairs of dictionary
    # [1]: value of item
    # [0]: key of item

# or even shorter, as Saish suggests:
def most_classes(d):
    return max(d, key=lambda k: len(d[k]))


> d = {'Jason Seifer': ['Ruby Foundations', 'Ruby on Rails Forms', 'Technology Foundations'],
       'Kenneth Love': ['Python Basics', 'Python Collections']}
> most_classes(d)
'Jason Seifer'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `lambda` operator

```
max(dict, key=lambda x:len(dict[x]))
```